# How can I display HTML pages in a Flex app, without using <iframe>?

Tags: html, apache-flex

I have a few HTML pages that I want to display in a Flex app. Since Flex has limited HTML support I figured I could convert the pages into PDFs, but since Flex webapps don't support PDFs I am in a bit of a pickle.

The pages I have are HTML, with text & images. What are my options for displaying this in a Flex web app?

I'd like something like a PDF where the user can select which pages they want to print, etc but whatever looks nice & works is fine for now. The freer the better, as I don't want to spend cash.

I don't like the `<iframe>` approach. It seems too chunky & not reliable.

Thanks!

Comment: What’s chunky/unreliable about `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the iFrame trick to make it appear like your HTML is a part of the Flex App.  If you Google "Flex iFrame" you'll find a bunch of information about it.

Also, there is a commercial component from Drumbeat Insight that may help you solve this.

Comment: I said Drumbeat Insight, not drumbeat.  I was referring to their HTML Component: http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent for Flex

Answer (score 0):

FlashPaper can be used to produce a swf that looks like a PDF with much of the same functionality.  You should be able to embed this swf in a Flex app easily.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/

Comment: It seems alright but I didn't see anywhere where the user can print x page w/out printing the entire document. Other than that, this is the best one I've found so far...unless there are other options I'm missing

Comment: Flash Paper has reached end of life; I'm not sure I'd recommend using it.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use mx:HTML which u can insert in a VBOX for example

```
<mx:VBox label="Embedded HTML mit PDF"  id="box"
         width="100%" 
         height="100%">

    <mx:HTML id="pdfHtml" location="test.html" width="100%" height="100%" />
</mx:VBox>
```